# 500 - Internal server error until someone logs into the server

Tags: iis-7

After my server boots I am unable to access any site until someone logs into the machine.  They can immediately log back out and it will continue to work until the machine is rebooted.

As a matter of fact I can't even hit the basic `http://server/welcome.png` until this has been done.  I cannot find any logs when this happens.

Comment: Is the website content on a remote (or possibly local) resource that is made available to users when the log in ?

Comment: There is a application that uses windows authentication but there is nothing like that on the default web site and I can't even access the built in stuff.

Comment: Sounds like something on the box requires a loaded user profile. You could try ticking "Load User Profile" for whichever App Pool is running the main site (usually DefaultAppPool, but I guarantee you that vanilla unmodified servers don't behave like this), and see if that gives (whatever it is) (whatever it wants). You could also try turning on Failed Request Tracing and tracing status code 500 after a reboot, though that might be iffy if the app pool's failing to load.